# How do I get the format of creationtime.month to be double digits instead of single?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that takes the creation date of a file and injects it into an xml tag. Everything works but the formatting of the date shows 2019-4-3 and I need the format to be 2019-04-03.

I have tried the 'tostring(MM)' and that has not worked for me. Anyone have any ideas? Here is a snippet of the code where I think the issue is. I can post the whole script if anyone wants to see it.

```
$filename="C:\Users\Public\file.xml"
$filename2="C:\Users\Public\file2.xml"


$month = (Get-ChildItem $filename).CreationTime.Month 
$day = (Get-ChildItem $filename).CreationTime.Day
$year = (Get-ChildItem $filename).CreationTime.Year
$hour = (Get-ChildItem $filename).CreationTime.Hour
$min = (Get-ChildItem $filename).CreationTime.Minute
$sec= (Get-ChildItem $filename).CreationTime.Second


$output=[string]$year+"-"+[string]$month+"-"+[string]$day+"T"+[string]$hour+":"+[string]$min+":"+[string]$sec+":00z"

Write-Host $output
```

The output of the dates are single digit and I need them double digits. Any ideas?

Comment: As an aside: generally, a sub-second time component requires `.` as the separator, not `:`.

Comment: Also: Time-zone suffix `z` indicates _UTC_, so `.CreationTimeUtc`, not `.CreationTime`, should be used; otherwise, a _local_ timestamp is mistakenly presented as if it were a UTC timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work assuming you don't actually need each part of the datetime as a separate variable:

```
$filename="C:\Users\Public\file.xml"
(Get-ChildItem $filename).creationtime.toString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')+':00z'
```

I don't know why the `toString()` method did not work for you previously unless you didn't quote contents inside the parentheses. The method doesn't always require an input argument, but with what you are trying it requires a string to be passed to it.

Comment: It's the OP's mistake, but worth pointing out: Time-zone suffix `z` indicates a UTC time stamp, so `.CreationTimeUtc`, not `.CreationTime`, should be used.

Answer (score 2):

You are constructing this the hard way. Formatting dates and times as strings is fully explained here: https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-dateformats.html

A simpler way to do this, and faster since right now you are getting the file info 6 times right now, would be to use the built-in `[datetime]` method `ToString()`.

```
(Get-Item $filename).CreationTimeUtc.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.00Z")
```

Notice that I used the `CreationTimeUtc` property instead of `CreationTime`, since the "Z" at the end of your string that you are creating indicates that this is the time in UTC (the "Z" stands for *Zulu time*, as explained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones)).

Answer (score 0):

To *complement* [TheMadTechnician's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55501243/45375):

Except for the `T` separating the date and time parts and a sub-second component, your format is the same as the [standard `u` date/time format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#UniversalSortable):

```
PS> (Get-Item /).CreationTimeUtc.ToString('u') -replace ' ', 'T'
2018-11-30T10:47:40Z
```

If you need an explicit zero-valued sub-second component, append `-replace 'Z$', '.00Z'` - note the use of `.`, not `:`, as the separator, because `.` is normally used.